# this parameter not passing expected element

Tags: javascript, input, this, onfocus

I have a dynamic set of input fields being generated.  They all get named sequentially and each has an onFocus() handler. Just before each Input element is a div with a corresponding Id where I grab a dollar value from.

```
<input type="hidden" name="balance" value="2500.0" />  
<div id="invoiceAmount0">$500.00</div>
<input type="text" size="8" id="invoiceBalance0" name="invoiceBalance0" value="" onfocus="setBalance(this)" />
<div id="invoiceAmount1">$500.00</div>
<input type="text" size="8" id="invoiceBalance1" name="invoiceBalance1" value="" onfocus="setBalance(this)" />
<div id="invoiceAmount2">$500.00</div>
<input type="text" size="8" id="invoiceBalance2" name="invoiceBalance2" value="" onfocus="setBalance(this)" />
```

The JS onFocus handler is as follows:

```
function setBalance(e) //e should be an input field element
{
  var balance = document.PaymentForm.balance.value;
  var remainder = balance;

  var index = 0;
  var paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance'+index);  //get the first input payment element
  while (paymentField != null && paymentField != e) //start with the first field and calculate the remaining balance
  {
    var paymentApplied = paymentField.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""); 
    remainder = remainder - paymentApplied;
    index++;
    paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance'+index);  
  }
  while (e == paymentField)  //set the selected elements value
  {
    var invoiceBalance = document.getElementById('in'+index).innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
    if (parseFloat(remainder) > parseFloat(invoiceBalance))
      e.value = parseFloat(invoiceBalance).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();    
    else
      e.value = parseFloat(remainder).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
    index++;
    paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance'+index); 
  }
  while (paymentField != null)  //blank out the rest of the input fields
  { 
    paymentField.value = ''; 
    index++;
    paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance'+index); 
  }
  e.select();
}
```

The concept here is to calculate the remaining balance and set the input field's value as the user focuses the fields.

The problem is that The "this" parameter is always set to the first Input element "invoiceBalance0".  I'm expecting it to be set to the element referring to it in it's onFocus handler.

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to duplicate the error you describe, but I did notice what appears to be a typo:

`var invoiceBalance = document.getElementById('in'+index).innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");`

looks like it should be

`var invoiceBalance = document.getElementById('invoiceAmount'+index).innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");`

```js
function setBalance(e) //e should be an input field element
  {
    var balance = document.querySelector('[name="balance"]').value;
    var remainder = balance;
    var index = 0;
    var paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance' + index); //get the first input payment element
    while (paymentField != null && paymentField != e) //start with the first field and calculate the remaining balance
    {
      var paymentApplied = paymentField.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
      remainder = remainder - paymentApplied;
      index++;
      paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance' + index);
    }
    while (e == paymentField) //set the selected elements value
    {
      var invoiceBalance = document.getElementById('invoiceAmount' + index).innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
      if (parseFloat(remainder) > parseFloat(invoiceBalance))
        e.value = parseFloat(invoiceBalance).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
      else
        e.value = parseFloat(remainder).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
      index++;
      paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance' + index);
    }
    while (paymentField != null) //blank out the rest of the input fields
    {
      paymentField.value = '';
      index++;
      paymentField = document.getElementById('invoiceBalance' + index);
    }
    e.select();
  }
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="balance" value="2500.0" />
<div id="invoiceAmount0">$500.00</div>
<input type="text" size="8" id="invoiceBalance0" name="invoiceBalance0" value="" onfocus="setBalance(this)" />
<div id="invoiceAmount1">$500.00</div>
<input type="text" size="8" id="invoiceBalance1" name="invoiceBalance1" value="" onfocus="setBalance(this)" />
<div id="invoiceAmount2">$500.00</div>
<input type="text" size="8" id="invoiceBalance2" name="invoiceBalance2" value="" onfocus="setBalance(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work after changing this line :

```
var invoiceBalance = document.getElementById('in'+index).innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")
```

To :

```
var invoiceBalance =  document.getElementById('invoiceBalance'+index).innerHTML.replace(/[^
0-9\.]+/g,"");
```

that because you don't have an id like `in[index]` but this form `invoiceBalance[index]`, hope that will help See
**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xygt5mc/)**.